# I cannot completely eliminate the weight on a bone to a random part of my character

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am attempting to weight paint my character and after debugging the endless bugs I have found with this new update I used automatic weights as a starting point. For some reason the automatic weight will sometimes end up on seemingly in a random part of the mesh. This is usually just an annoying bug but all you have to do is delete all the weight. However, for some reason this one small part of my mesh near the armpit just won't stop being influenced by the head bone.

[image]

As you can see I twisted the neck 180 degrees so that you could clearly see the clipping problem near the armpit circled in red.

Comment: In that case, select this part of your mesh in Edit mode, go in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, select the group that is called by the name of the neck bone, and click on the Remove button... sometimes the weight paint brush can't completely remove vertices from a group, I don't know why...

Comment: It can't do it because weight paint works with occlusion only. So indeed to go to edit mode and remove the vertices from the group is the fast way to do it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea until you realize that that armpit area is not my only problem. I also need to do the same things to areas of the head where I simply can't weight paint. Parts that are going to be controlled by the head bone